# Source-code-compiled qt on command

Tags: linux, shell, opensuse, alias, qt

**Backstory**

I am using opensuse, there are built-in qt4 and qt5 in my system. I need more complete tools from qt for compiling a file, that’s why I installed from source code via [qt website](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source). I have successfully installed it in my system.

**Problem**

The problem is I need to run this on terminal, and I’m not sure how to make *qmake* directed to this source code compiled qt. Or is it possible just to make an alias for this? The path to the source compiled qt is */home/hafiz/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator*.

Please help me on running this on terminal! Thanks!